# Border below button

Tags: html, css

I'm a little bit stuck with a small problem regarding CSS:
I've got a button with a transition, during this transition my arrow does move, however, the shadow box below it doesn't move along with it.

Any idea/suggestions how I could fix this?

```
<div class="download_btn download_button">
    <a class="btn left">
        <span class="left icon icon-lock"></span>
        <span class="right title"><span class="arrow-right"></span>Click here</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Fiddle:
    https://jsfiddle.net/5L6ctw6m/2

Comment: By _"transaction"_, do you mean _"transition"_?

Comment: Yes, sorry that's exactly what I mean. Editted the post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick solution, you can take this variant

https://jsfiddle.net/zndemLtd/1/

```
<a class="btn left">
  <span class="left icon icon-lock">
    <span class="arrow-right"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="right title">Click here</span>
</a>
```

Also, CSS was updated a bit.

```
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn .btn.left span.arrow-right {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn .btn.left span.arrow-right:before {
  right: 10px;
    top: 25px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 7px;
    background: #030e15;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn .btn:hover span.arrow-right {
  left: calc(100% + 5px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks with this code I could make it work for my needs, awesome!

Comment: And if I would want to add a row of text below that how could I do that? 

Simply putting this won't do the trick:

<span class="right title">Click here<br>text</span>

Answer (score 0):

Hey actually you have used two different value for box shadow in .landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn .btn classs so it is creating a problem. Please check the following output.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'play-regular';
  src: url('../fonts/play-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/play-regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/play-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/play-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/play-regular.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
html { 
 background: url(../img/gradient.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-color: #1D577C;
}
body {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'play-regular';
  background-color: transparent;
}
/* Variables */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 995px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 98%;
  }
}
.page_wrapper {
  width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 1420px) {
  .page_wrapper {
    width: 98%;
  }
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.align_center {
  text-align: center;
}
.align_left {
  text-align: left;
}
.align_right {
  text-align: right;
}
.float_left {
  float: left;
}
.float_right {
  float: right;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src: url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?-1vhccs');
  src: url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix-1vhccs') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/icomoon.woff?-1vhccs') format('woff'), url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf?-1vhccs') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/icomoon.svg?-1vhccs#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.icon-lock:before {
  content: "\e606";
}
.icon-help:before {
  content: "\e604";
}
.icon-unlocked2:before {
  content: "\e602";
}
.icon-file-add:before {
  content: "\e603";
}
.icon-arrow-down3:before {
  content: "\e60a";
}
.icon-question:before {
  content: "\f128";
}
.icon-download:before {
  content: "\e600";
}
.icon-hand:before {
  content: "\f0a4";
}
.icon-unlocked:before {
  content: "\e601";
}
.icon-comment:before {
  content: "\e605";
}
.icon-file-text2:before {
  content: "\e926";
}
.icon-folder-open:before {
  content: "\e930";
}
.icon-unlocked3:before {
  content: "\e990";
}
.icon-download2:before {
  content: "\e9c2";
}
.icon-arrow-down:before {
  content: "\ea36";
}
.icon-arrow-down2:before {
  content: "\ea3e";
}
.icon-point-right:before {
  content: "\ea04";
}
/* ========================================= grid css =============================================== */
.content {
  padding: 10px;
}
.row {
  zoom: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-rendering: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.row > [class*="col_"] {
  min-height: 1px;
}
[class*="col_xs_"] {
  float: left;
}
.col_xs_1 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col_xs_1_2 {
  width: 50%;
  *width: 49.969%;
}
.col_xs_1_3 {
  width: 33.3333%;
  *width: 33.3023%;
}
.col_xs_2_3 {
  width: 66.6667%;
  *width: 66.6357%;
}
.col_xs_1_4 {
  width: 25%;
  *width: 24.969%;
}
.col_xs_3_4 {
  width: 75%;
  *width: 74.969%;
}
.col_xs_1_5 {
  width: 20%;
  *width: 19.969%;
}
.col_xs_2_5 {
  width: 40%;
  *width: 39.969%;
}
.col_xs_3_5 {
  width: 60%;
  *width: 59.969%;
}
.col_xs_4_5 {
  width: 80%;
  *width: 79.969%;
}
.col_xs_1_6 {
  width: 16.6667%;
  *width: 16.6357%;
}
.col_xs_5_6 {
  width: 83.3333%;
  *width: 83.3023%;
}
.col_xs_1_8 {
  width: 12.5%;
  *width: 12.469%;
}
.col_xs_3_8 {
  width: 37.5%;
  *width: 37.469%;
}
.col_xs_5_8 {
  width: 62.5%;
  *width: 62.469%;
}
.col_xs_7_8 {
  width: 87.5%;
  *width: 87.469%;
}
.col_xs_1_12 {
  width: 8.3333%;
  *width: 8.3023%;
}
.col_xs_5_12 {
  width: 41.6667%;
  *width: 41.6357%;
}
.col_xs_7_12 {
  width: 58.3333%;
  *width: 58.3023%;
}
.col_xs_11_12 {
  width: 91.6667%;
  *width: 91.6357%;
}
.col_xs_1_24 {
  width: 4.1667%;
  *width: 4.1357%;
}
.col_xs_5_24 {
  width: 20.8333%;
  *width: 20.8023%;
}
.col_xs_7_24 {
  width: 29.1667%;
  *width: 29.1357%;
}
.col_xs_11_24 {
  width: 45.8333%;
  *width: 45.8023%;
}
.col_xs_13_24 {
  width: 54.1667%;
  *width: 54.1357%;
}
.col_xs_17_24 {
  width: 70.8333%;
  *width: 70.8023%;
}
.col_xs_19_24 {
  width: 79.1667%;
  *width: 79.1357%;
}
.col_xs_22_24 {
  width: 91.6667%;
  *width: 91.6367%;
}
.col_xs_23_24 {
  width: 95.8333%;
  *width: 95.8023%;
}
@media (min-device-width: 769px) and (min-width: 769px) {
  [class*="col_sm_"] {
    float: left;
  }
  .col_sm_1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col_sm_1_2 {
    width: 50%;
    *width: 49.969%;
  }
  .col_sm_1_3 {
    width: 33.3333%;
    *width: 33.3023%;
  }
  .col_sm_2_3 {
    width: 66.6667%;
    *width: 66.6357%;
  }
  .col_sm_1_4 {
    width: 25%;
    *width: 24.969%;
  }
  .col_sm_3_4 {
    width: 75%;
    *width: 74.969%;
  }
  .col_sm_1_5 {
    width: 20%;
    *width: 19.969%;
  }
  .col_sm_2_5 {
    width: 40%;
    *width: 39.969%;
  }
  .col_sm_3_5 {
    width: 60%;
    *width: 59.969%;
  }
  .col_sm_4_5 {
    width: 80%;
    *width: 79.969%;
  }
  .col_sm_1_6 {
    width: 16.6667%;
    *width: 16.6357%;
  }
  .col_sm_5_6 {
    width: 83.3333%;
    *width: 83.3023%;
  }
  .col_sm_1_8 {
    width: 12.5%;
    *width: 12.469%;
  }
  .col_sm_3_8 {
    width: 37.5%;
    *width: 37.469%;
  }
  .col_sm_5_8 {
    width: 62.5%;
    *width: 62.469%;
  }
  .col_sm_7_8 {
    width: 87.5%;
    *width: 87.469%;
  }
  .col_sm_1_12 {
    width: 8.3333%;
    *width: 8.3023%;
  }
  .col_sm_5_12 {
    width: 41.6667%;
    *width: 41.6357%;
  }
  .col_sm_7_12 {
    width: 58.3333%;
    *width: 58.3023%;
  }
  .col_sm_11_12 {
    width: 91.6667%;
    *width: 91.6357%;
  }
  .col_sm_1_24 {
    width: 4.1667%;
    *width: 4.1357%;
  }
  .col_sm_5_24 {
    width: 20.8333%;
    *width: 20.8023%;
  }
  .col_sm_7_24 {
    width: 29.1667%;
    *width: 29.1357%;
  }
  .col_sm_11_24 {
    width: 45.8333%;
    *width: 45.8023%;
  }
  .col_sm_13_24 {
    width: 54.1667%;
    *width: 54.1357%;
  }
  .col_sm_17_24 {
    width: 70.8333%;
    *width: 70.8023%;
  }
  .col_sm_19_24 {
    width: 79.1667%;
    *width: 79.1357%;
  }
  .col_sm_22_24 {
    width: 91.6667%;
    *width: 91.6367%;
  }
  .col_sm_23_24 {
    width: 95.8333%;
    *width: 95.8023%;
  }
}
@media (min-device-width: 992px) and (min-width: 992px) {
  [class*="col_md_"] {
    float: left;
  }
  .col_md_1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col_md_1_2 {
    width: 50%;
    *width: 49.969%;
  }
  .col_md_1_3 {
    width: 33.3333%;
    *width: 33.3023%;
  }
  .col_md_2_3 {
    width: 66.6667%;
    *width: 66.6357%;
  }
  .col_md_1_4 {
    width: 25%;
    *width: 24.969%;
  }
  .col_md_3_4 {
    width: 75%;
    *width: 74.969%;
  }
  .col_md_1_5 {
    width: 20%;
    *width: 19.969%;
  }
  .col_md_2_5 {
    width: 40%;
    *width: 39.969%;
  }
  .col_md_3_5 {
    width: 60%;
    *width: 59.969%;
  }
  .col_md_4_5 {
    width: 80%;
    *width: 79.969%;
  }
  .col_md_1_6 {
    width: 16.6667%;
    *width: 16.6357%;
  }
  .col_md_5_6 {
    width: 83.3333%;
    *width: 83.3023%;
  }
  .col_md_1_8 {
    width: 12.5%;
    *width: 12.469%;
  }
  .col_md_3_8 {
    width: 37.5%;
    *width: 37.469%;
  }
  .col_md_5_8 {
    width: 62.5%;
    *width: 62.469%;
  }
  .col_md_7_8 {
    width: 87.5%;
    *width: 87.469%;
  }
  .col_md_1_12 {
    width: 8.3333%;
    *width: 8.3023%;
  }
  .col_md_5_12 {
    width: 41.6667%;
    *width: 41.6357%;
  }
  .col_md_7_12 {
    width: 58.3333%;
    *width: 58.3023%;
  }
  .col_md_11_12 {
    width: 91.6667%;
    *width: 91.6357%;
  }
  .col_md_1_24 {
    width: 4.1667%;
    *width: 4.1357%;
  }
  .col_md_5_24 {
    width: 20.8333%;
    *width: 20.8023%;
  }
  .col_md_7_24 {
    width: 29.1667%;
    *width: 29.1357%;
  }
  .col_md_11_24 {
    width: 45.8333%;
    *width: 45.8023%;
  }
  .col_md_13_24 {
    width: 54.1667%;
    *width: 54.1357%;
  }
  .col_md_17_24 {
    width: 70.8333%;
    *width: 70.8023%;
  }
  .col_md_19_24 {
    width: 79.1667%;
    *width: 79.1357%;
  }
  .col_md_22_24 {
    width: 91.6667%;
    *width: 91.6367%;
  }
  .col_md_23_24 {
    width: 95.8333%;
    *width: 95.8023%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  [class*="col_lg_"] {
    float: left;
  }
  .col_lg_1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col_lg_1_2 {
    width: 50%;
    *width: 49.969%;
  }
  .col_lg_1_3 {
    width: 33.3333%;
    *width: 33.3023%;
  }
  .col_lg_2_3 {
    width: 66.6667%;
    *width: 66.6357%;
  }
  .col_lg_1_4 {
    width: 25%;
    *width: 24.969%;
  }
  .col_lg_3_4 {
    width: 75%;
    *width: 74.969%;
  }
  .col_lg_1_5 {
    width: 20%;
    *width: 19.969%;
  }
  .col_lg_2_5 {
    width: 40%;
    *width: 39.969%;
  }
  .col_lg_3_5 {
    width: 60%;
    *width: 59.969%;
  }
  .col_lg_4_5 {
    width: 80%;
    *width: 79.969%;
  }
  .col_lg_1_6 {
    width: 16.6667%;
    *width: 16.6357%;
  }
  .col_lg_5_6 {
    width: 83.3333%;
    *width: 83.3023%;
  }
  .col_lg_1_8 {
    width: 12.5%;
    *width: 12.469%;
  }
  .col_lg_3_8 {
    width: 37.5%;
    *width: 37.469%;
  }
  .col_lg_5_8 {
    width: 62.5%;
    *width: 62.469%;
  }
  .col_lg_7_8 {
    width: 87.5%;
    *width: 87.469%;
  }
  .col_lg_1_12 {
    width: 8.3333%;
    *width: 8.3023%;
  }
  .col_lg_5_12 {
    width: 41.6667%;
    *width: 41.6357%;
  }
  .col_lg_7_12 {
    width: 58.3333%;
    *width: 58.3023%;
  }
  .col_lg_11_12 {
    width: 91.6667%;
    *width: 91.6357%;
  }
  .col_lg_1_24 {
    width: 4.1667%;
    *width: 4.1357%;
  }
  .col_lg_5_24 {
    width: 20.8333%;
    *width: 20.8023%;
  }
  .col_lg_7_24 {
    width: 29.1667%;
    *width: 29.1357%;
  }
  .col_lg_11_24 {
    width: 45.8333%;
    *width: 45.8023%;
  }
  .col_lg_13_24 {
    width: 54.1667%;
    *width: 54.1357%;
  }
  .col_lg_17_24 {
    width: 70.8333%;
    *width: 70.8023%;
  }
  .col_lg_19_24 {
    width: 79.1667%;
    *width: 79.1357%;
  }
  .col_lg_22_24 {
    width: 91.6667%;
    *width: 91.6367%;
  }
  .col_lg_23_24 {
    width: 95.8333%;
    *width: 95.8023%;
  }
}
/* =============================== PAGE STYLES ================================ */
.landing_page {
  display: block;
}
.landing_page .header_title {
  background: url('../img/gradient-menu.png') center;
  height: 45px;
}
.landing_page .header_title p {
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 45px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 8px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 18px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-weight: 700;
}
.landing_page .step_container {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.landing_page .step_container h4.heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #141b29;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.landing_page .step_container h4.heading i,
.landing_page .step_container h4.heading span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.landing_page .step_container h4.heading span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .text_part {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .down {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 50px;
}

.landing_page .step_container .download_container .down span {
  background: #0e3a57;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
  top: -10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .down span i {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  display: block;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_file {
  width: 478px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_file .icon_container {
  float: left;
  margin: 34px;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_file .download_text {
  float: right;
  width: 280px;
  margin-top: 42px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_file .download_text p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_file .download_text h4 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn .btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 53px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #888;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 10px;
}



.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn .btn span.icon {
  font-size: 23px;
  background-color: #071d2b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #030e15;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #030e15;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #888;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn .btn span.left {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn .btn span.title {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #0a2b41;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #0a2b41;
  background-color: #0e3a57;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn .btn span.right {
  float: right;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  width: 165px;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn .btn span.icon,
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn .btn span.title {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn .btn.left span.arrow-right {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0 0 0 #071d2b, -10px 3px 0 0 #030e15;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 0 0 #071d2b, -10px 3px 0 0 #030e15;
  border-left: 10px solid #071d2b;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s;
  -transition: all .15s;
  -webkit-transition-property: left, right;
  transition-property: left, right;
}

.landing_page .step_container .download_container .download_btn .btn:hover span.arrow-right {
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/landing_page1.css">


</head><body id="the_body" style="margin:0; height:100%; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;">
    <div class="landing_page" id="landing_page">
        <div class="step_container">
        
            <div class="wrapper clearfix" style="overflow: hidden;">
                <div class="download_container">
              
                    <div class="down">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col_sm_1 zoomIn">
               
                            <div class="download_btn download_button">
                                <a class="btn left">
                                    <span class="left icon icon-lock"></span>
                                    <span class="right title"><span class="arrow-right"></span>Click here</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
       
       
       
      
    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

    
        </div>
    </div>



   


</div></body></html>
```

Comment: It looks neat, however when I zoom in to 175% it has this kind of weird box. I had this problem initially and tried to fix that with some modifying, but ended up with the problem I'm having :P